# What can I use to substitute &nbsp;&nbsp; in HTML?

Tags: html, css, layout, whitespace

`&nbsp;&nbsp;` is ugly, I think.

Comment: Depends what you are trying to achieve by doing this.

Comment: Why do you want to substitute it anyway?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Margin and/or Padding. (css properties), like so:

```
<p style='padding-left : 10px'>Hello</p>
```

(It's worth noting that it's generally considered bad-practice to put an inline style like that; you typically declare a selector in an external css file and set the class/whatever appropriately.)

Comment: Actually, this is not helpful always. I think if you need a &nbsp element is probably because you don't have content in <p></p>

Answer (score 22):

In CSS try:

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

Answer (score 6):

In CSS, Add

```
pre{
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;
  white-space: -pre-wrap;
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
}
```

```
<pre>
    is not ugly anymore
</pre>
```

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem when I realised I will have empty tags. I didn't want to set a fixed height and it was to late to change the html. I wanted to add a space in the css, the substitute for `&nbsp`, so I added the space before the element, using `:before` (it needs to be specified via unicode).

```
p:before {
    content: "\00a0";
}
```

Hope this solution helps someone. The solution with padding didn't work for my problem.

Answer (score 4):

`&#160;` is alternative but it's also ugly

Beautiful solution is available in css.

If u need space at start of paragraph the u can use

`p {text-indent: 10px; }`

If u need spacing between word use like this

```
H2 { word-spacing: 3pt }
```

see here for more options http://www.hypergurl.com/csstutorial7.html

You can give these style to html by inline, external and from in-page(`<head>....</head>`)

Comment: Yes &#160; is also ugly, but it is tolerated by Windows Phone 8 (VS Express 2012 Phone), while &nbsp; leads to an error (which can be ignored but is always displayed).

Answer (score 2):

How about the `letter-spacing` and/or `word-spacing` CSS properties?

Answer (score 1):

You should use margin or padding properties with your elements to adjust whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

I used  a span between two buttons.

`<span style="margin-left:70px;"></span>`

It spaced everything just where I needed it.  I tried creating a "spacer" div,  but that pushed one of the buttons below the other.  I think that was because I was using a margin-bottom:30px; in the div.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
&nbsp;  non-breaking space: ' '
&emsp;  em space: ' '
&ensp;  en space: ' '
&thinsp;    thin space: ' '
```

SIX-PER-EM SPACE

```
<p>I will display &#8198;</p>
<p>I will display &#x2006;</p>
```

EN QUAD space example

```
<p>I will display &#8192;tt</p>
<p>I will display &#x2000;tt</p>
```

EM QUAD

```
<p>I will display &#8193;tt</p>
<p>I will display &#x2001;tt</p>
```

Table

```
Char    Dec Hex Entity  Name
    8192    2000        EN QUAD
    8193    2001        EM QUAD
    8194    2002    &ensp;  EN SPACE
    8195    2003    &emsp;  EM SPACE
    8196    2004        THREE-PER-EM SPACE
    8197    2005        FOUR-PER-EM SPACE
    8198    2006        SIX-PER-EM SPACE
    8199    2007        FIGURE SPACE
    8200    2008        PUNCTUATION SPACE
    8201    2009    &thinsp;    THIN SPACE
    8202    200A        HAIR SPACE
​   8203    200B        ZERO WIDTH SPACE
```

Basically you can replace 4 space with

```
&emsp; == &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want replace all `&nbsp` with simple spaces   in your HTML source code and KEEP the spaces in browser render view, like **pre** tag, you can use in CSS:

```
white-space:break-spaces
```